# How to wrap any function

Tags: c#, templates, delegates

What I want.

```cs
Invoke(Action action);
Invoke(Func func);

Invoke(Action action)
{
  some action before
  action()
  some action after
}

Invoke(Func func)
{
  some action before
  res = func()
  some action after
  return res;
}
```

Call example:

```cs
Invoke(() => Tread.Sleep(1000));
var res = Invoke(() => return 5);
```

But in instead of Func there can be Func , Func <T,R> and so on.
The main idea is to wrap any code inside common blocks.
Reflection is possible.

I can write many methods like:

```cs
Invoke(Action<T> action)
{
  some action before
  action()
  some action after
}

Invoke(Action<T,T1> action)
{
  some action before
  action()
  some action after
}

Invoke(Action<T, T1, T2> action)
{
  some action before
  action()
  some action after
}
```

but it is too annoying.

Comment: Just pass an instance of `Delegate` to your method and an object-array containing the parameters - if any.

Comment: Is it enough to just keep what you have and pass a wrapper? `Invoke(() => action(p1,p2,p3))` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in an instance of `Delegate` to your method:

```
void Invoke(Delegate d, params object[] args)
{
    // do soemthing beforehand
    d.DynamicInvoke(args);
    // do something aferwards
}
```

However you lose any type-safety and have to check the number and types of the args being passed yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on whether your `Invoke` method needs to modify the delegate's arguments or not.

If it does not, then you can persist type-safety like this:

```
void Invoke(Action action)
{
    // some action before
    action();
    // some action after
}

TResult Invoke<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
{
    // some action before
    TResult res = func();
    // some action after
    return res;
}
```

Then you can use lambda expressions if you need to close over the arguments:

```
Invoke(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
int res = Invoke(() => int.Parse("5"));
```

If your `Invoke` method does modify the arguments, then that cannot be done in a type-safe way that accommodates any function.